# Removing rows that contain certain value and removing odd numbered columns

Tags: python, rows

trying to work with two text files in python. The goal is to firstly, remove all rows that contain a 3 or 4. After this, remove the first 6 columns entirely. I have figured out how to remove the 6 coloumns:

```
f = open("filename.txt", "r")
g = open("filename1.txt", "w")

for line in f:
    if line.strip():
        g.write("\t".join(line.split()[6:]) + "\n")
f.close()
g.close()
```

However, I cannot figure out how to remove a row based on a repeating character/occurence (in this case, the digit 3 or 4 appear in a row should remove that row entirely). And then lastly, to remove all odd columns, but not totally remove them. Essentially, remove the odd columns and add them to end the of the text file (a new text file to write to, that is -- everything is being written to the next text file).

Comment: do you want to remove it if the number is `33`?  or just `3`?

Comment: No, it's a bunch of a columns/rows. In certain rows there is the digit 3. In other rows there is the digit 4. I just want to remove rows that contain  3 and 4s. Or maybe if it is easier, anything 3 or greater.

Comment: you want remove only if 3,4 repeat or if they present even once?

Comment: Something like `if "3" in line or "4" in line: continue`?

Comment: Remove 3 or 4 if they appear at all in the file. So, if 3 or 4 appears at all in any given row or column, remove that row.

Comment: 1 3 4  5 <--- this would remove the row entirely because it has a 3. Likewise, the same concept if a 4 is contained in the row also.

Comment: @user1985793 -- but to be clear, `1 33 44 5` would *not* get removed.

Comment: and the input is rectangular? number of elements in each row is same?

Comment: @mgilson -- You are correct. 33, 44 would not get removed. Only 3 and 4. However, I'm not sure how to do this. If it makes it easier to simply remove any value 3 or higher and remove that row, then that is fine, too. I just want to get started on this, but appreciate the foresight and different test cases.

Comment: @Anil -- Yes, rectangular. All rows and columns have same amount of elements.

Comment: @user1985793 posted the answer, check if it is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lines = [line.strip() for line in open('file.txt')]
nlines=[]
for line in lines:
    if 3 not in map(int,line.split()) and 4 not in map(int,line.split()): nlines.append(line)
for x in nlines:
    y=x.split()
    y=y[1::2]
    print ' '.join(y)
```

file.txt

```
3 4 5 6 7 12 34 56
2 5 6 7 8 11 10 7
4 5 6 7 8 44 55 12
33 66 88 99 79 1 2 5
```

by removing lines containing 3 or 4 and removing odd numbered columns

output

```
5 7 11 7
66 99 1 5
```

Comment: Very nice. What if I wanted to do this same thing except if 3 or 4 occur in only a single column? e.g. Column 3. If column 3 has row 3 or 4, then delete only rows in that column. (sorry this is aside from my main question, but am curious on how to do so).

Also: wondering, this is part of my main question, since you removed the odd numbered columns. How can I still keep that and write those odd number columns to the end of a new text file.

Comment: for the input I wrote, how should be the output? (by keeping odd numbered columns at end of the file?)

Comment: It should be in the same format. It should just add to the rectangular format as is. Basically, just continue the same row and column format except just add it all the way to the end. Basically, add the extra rows and columns in.

Comment: what is the final thing you should do? because you said three things which go in different directions. clearly explain what you want to do finally.

Comment: Ok, sorry. Here is final explanation:
1) Go through column 2. If 3 or 4 is contained in column 2, remove that row from column 2.
2) Delete odd numbered columns and then paste it in the same format over to the new text file. Keeping all format, etc the same (which is the same rectangular format with same numbered rows and columns). Just add it to the END of the new text file.

Comment: you mean to go through only column 2 or all columns in that manner?